# Insight on why this equality may be true

Tags: proof-explanation

I was messing around and noticed that it seems like $$\text{arctanh}(1/x) = \Re(\text{arctanh}(x))$$
Does anyone have any insight on why this is true, or how to prove it?

Comment: One side is going to be a complex number. Did you mean that the real part of both sides are equal?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit, I meant the real part.

Comment: take the derivative on both side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\text{arctanh}(x)&=\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\\
\implies\text{arctanh}(1/x)&=\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+\frac1x}{1-\frac1x}\right)\\
&=\frac12\log\left(-\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\\&=\text{arctanh}(x)+\frac12\log(-1)\\&=\text{arctanh}(x)+\frac12\log(1)+\frac {i\pi}2\\&=\text{arctanh}(x)+\frac{i\pi}2\end{align}$$
So the real parts are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Use
$$\text{arctanh}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\log(1+x)-\frac{1}{2}\log(1-x)$$
for real $x$ observe $\text{arctanh}(1/x)$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\pm\frac{1+x}{|x|}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\mp\frac{1-x}{|x|}\right)$$

use $\log(a b)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ to get rid of denominator. Then use $\log(-1)=\pi i$ to get
$$=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1-x\right)-\text{sign}(x)\frac{\pi i}{2}=\text{arctanh}(x)-\text{sign}(x)\frac{\pi i}{2}$$
which means the function $\text{arctanh}(x)$ is not completely invariant under inversion.

EDIT:

We can plot the imaginary part of the difference of the functions arctanh$(x)-$arctanh$(1/x)$ for example in the computer algebra program Mathematica:

[image]

This confirms that the sign$(x)$ is indeed necessary in front of the $-\frac{\pi i}{2}$ imaginary part of the function difference.

Comment: Yes. But the statement in the question (regarding real part) is correct :)

Comment: @JohnDoe I agree. Still curious whether there is a sign(x) attached to the imaginary part or not. Perhaps it depends on where we put the branch cut...

Comment: Hmm, I don't think its required. See my answer, we just get $\log(-1)$. In your answer, you can arrive to this conclusion as follows: $$\frac12\log(1+x)-\frac12\log(\pm|x|)-\frac12\log(1-x)+\frac12\log(\pm|x|)\\=\frac12\log(1+x)-\frac12\log(1-x)+\frac12\log\left(\frac\mp\pm\right)\\=\frac12\log(1+x)-\frac12\log(1-x)+\frac12\log(-1)$$So there is no $\text{sign}(x)$ present.

Comment: @JohnDoe I think there is a typo in the first line of your calculation in the comment (the $\log(\pm |x|)$ would just cancel this way). Regarding your second line, couldn't we in the same spirit get $-\log(\mp |x|)+\log(\pm |x|)=\log(\frac{\pm}{\mp})=\log(-1)$ as well as $-\log(\mp |x|)+\log(\pm |x|)=-\log(\frac{\mp}{\pm})=-\log(-1)$? I think all this shows that one should have a more careful treatment of the branchcut in place. Perhaps by going to exponential representation of complexified $x$ and considering an $\epsilon\to 0$ regularization for the angle argument...

Comment: @JohnDoe see the edit of my answer for a numerical check of the analytic calculation.

Comment: Ah yes, there is a typo, one of those was meant to be $\mp$ rather than $\pm$. And yes, I suppose you are right, that is interesting... nice! :)